# When restarting thin via Capistrano changes aren't picked up

Tags: capistrano, deployment, thin

In my deploy.rb I have the following tasks:

```
namespace :deploy do
    task :start, :roles => :app do
        run "cd #{current_path} && bundle exec thin start -C config/thin.yml"
    end

    task :stop, :roles => :app do
        run "cd #{current_path} && bundle exec thin stop -C config/thin.yml"
    end

    task :restart, :roles => :app do
        run "cd #{current_path} && bundle exec thin restart -C config/thin.yml"
    end 
end
```

When I run `cap deploy:restart` via `cap deploy` recent code changes are not picked up. However, if I subsequently run `cap deploy:stop` and cap `cap deploy:start` all changes are picked up.

Why doesn't thin recognize the new current directory?

Comment: I am having this same problem.  Any solution?